# How to order a Table to tables based on 1 single data part of it?

Tags: lua, tabletop-simulator

I am a hobbyest making mods in TableTop Simulator using LUA and have a question that I can not seam to work out.

I have a number of "objects" which is a table in TTS that contains various data for those objects. For example.. obj.position = {x,y,z}... and can be accessed at the axis level as well.

```
obj.position = {5,10,15} -- x,y,z
obj.position.x == 5
```

This is an example. The makers of TTS have made it so you can access all the parts like that. So I can acess the object.. and then its various parts. There is a heap, like name, mesh, difuse and a ton more. roations{x,y,z} etc etc

Anyway. I have a table of objects... and would like to order those objects based on the positional data of the x axis.. so highest to lowest. So if I have a table and obj1 in that table is x=3 and obj2 is x=1 and obj3 = x=2 it would be sorted as obj2,obj3,obj1

Pseudo code:

```
tableOfObjects = {obj1,obj2,obj3}
--[[
tableOfObjectsp[1] == obj1
tableOfObjectsp[2] == obj2
tableOfObjectsp[3] == obj3

tableOfObjectsp[1].position.x == 3
tableOfObjectsp[2].position.x == 1
tableOfObjectsp[4].position.x == 2
--]]
---After Sort it would look this list
tableOfObjects = {obj1,obj3,obj2}
    --[[
tableOfObjectsp[1] == obj1
tableOfObjectsp[2] == obj3
tableOfObjectsp[3] == obj2

tableOfObjectsp[1].position.x == 3
tableOfObjectsp[2].position.x == 2
tableOfObjectsp[3].position.x == 1
--]]
```

I hope I am making sense. I am self taught in the last few months!

So basically I have a table of objects and want to sort the objects in that table based on a single value attached to each individual object in the table. In this case the obj.position.x

Thanks!

Comment: Let me get this strait, you want the max value out of {obj1, obj2, obj3} to be the first index in the table, and the min value to be last?

Comment: I would like to order the objects in the table from table[1]-> end based on the position.x of each object. So if the positions of the x axis in the world space would be like... 3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `table.sort`. The first argument is the table to sort, the second is a function to compare items.

Example:

```
t = {
    {str = 42, dex = 10, wis = 100},
    {str = 18, dex = 30, wis = 5}
}

table.sort(t, function (k1, k2)
    return k1.str < k2.str
end)
```

[This article has more information](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.6)

Answer (score 0):

```
table.sort(tableOfObjects, function(a, b) return a.position.x > b.position.x end)
```

This line will sort your table tableOfObjects in descending order by the x-coordinate.

To reverse order, replace > by <.

From the Lua reference manual:

> table.sort (list [, comp])
>
> Sorts list elements in a given order, in-place, from list[1] to
>   list[#list]. If comp is given, then it must be a function that
>   receives two list elements and returns true when the first element
>   must come before the second in the final order (so that, after the
>   sort, i < j implies not comp(list[j],list[i])). If comp is not given,
>   then the standard Lua operator < is used instead.
>
> Note that the comp function must define a strict partial order over
>   the elements in the list; that is, it must be asymmetric and
>   transitive. Otherwise, no valid sort may be possible.
>
> The sort algorithm is not stable: elements considered equal by the
>   given order may have their relative positions changed by the sort.

So in other words table.sort will sort a table in ascending order by its values.
If you want to order descending or by something other than the table value (like the x-coordinate of your table value's position in your case) you have to provide a function that tells Lua which element will come first.

Answer (score -3):

you can create a function that handles this exact thing:

```
local function fix_table(t)
    local x_data = {};
    local inds = {};
    local rt = {};
    for i = 1, #t do
        x_data[#x_data + 1] = t[i].position.x;
        inds[t[i].position.x] = t[i];
    end
    local min_index = math.min(table.unpack(x_data));
    local max_index = math.max(table.unpack(x_data));
    for i = min_index, max_index do
        if inds[i] ~= nil then
            rt[#rt + 1] = inds[i];
        end
    end
    return rt;
end
local mytable = {obj1, obj2, obj3};
mytable = fix_table(mytable);
```

`fix_table` first takes in every x value inside of the given table, and also places a new index inside the table `inds` according to each x value (so that they will be ordered from least to greatest), then it gets the smallest value in the `x_data` array table, which is used to traverse the `inds` table in order. fix_table checks to make sure that `inds[i]` is not equal to `nil` before it increases the size of the return table `rt` so that every value in rt is ordered from greatest to least, starting at index `1`, and ending at index `#rt`, finally `rt` is returned.

I hope this helped.

Comment: why not simply use `table.sort`?

Comment: also using '#inds' in a table and then checking `if inds[i] ~= nil` doesn't make any sense as you cannot reach a nil-value using `#inds`. `unpack` is deprecated. use `table.unpack` instead

Comment: @Piglet I use Lua 5.1

Comment: @Piglet, I beg to differ, imagine if obj3.position.x was some crazy number far apart from the other x values, then trying to index everything in between obj3.position.x and the last valid index would return nil, in which case if I did not check `if inds[i] == nil` then I would be trying to index a nil value, and thus an error would occur and the thread would halt. Remember I am iterating from the lowest index to the highest index. And if `#inds` doesn't cut it then the highest index would simply be `math.max(unpack(x_data));` :)